# Annotate anonymous inner class

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to annotate an anonymous inner class in Java?

In this example could you add a class level annotation to Class2?

```
public void method1() {
  add(new Class2() {
    public void method3() {}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No. You'd need to promote it to a "proper" class. It can still be scoped within the outer class if necessary, so it doesn't need to be a top-level class, or public, or whatever. But it does need a proper class definition to attach the annotation to.

Comment: The "proper" class can even be defined within the method, so that its scope is local to the method and design-wise it remains an internal implementation detail of the method.

Comment: If you are surprised by @amichair's description of local classes (like I was) note that it is new to JDK8 and the docs are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: Apparently local classes have been around since Java 1.1... but they are still surprising :-)

Comment: Note that since Java 8 you can add a class level annotation to anonymous classes as well, see [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40793526/2448440).

Answer (score 20):

Yes, [as mentioned by yegor256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14801163/1026104), it is possible, since [JDK 8 adopted JSR 308 (type annotations)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-architect-annotations-2177655.html).

So now whenever an annotation is decorated by `@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})`, it can be used for annotating an anonymous class at runtime. For instance:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}

Object o = new @MyAnnotation("Hello") Object() {};
```

The tricky part is how to access the annotation:

```
    Class<?> c = o.getClass();
    AnnotatedType type = c.getAnnotatedSuperclass();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(type.getAnnotations()));
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to access these kind of annotations? I could not find official documentation that I need to access them with `o.getClass().getAnnotatedSuperclass().getAnnotations()` which seems strange and counter-intuitive to me

Comment: I don't think a `TYPE_USE` annotation is what the OP is asking about. The question is about attaching a `TYPE` annotation like to a regular class definition.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I do not think the OP is asking about `TYPE` annotations. The question is about anonymous classes and any possible annotations.

Answer (score 11):

Not yet.  This feature is suggested by [JSR 308](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html), and may be included in future versions of Java.

Comment: You may want to add an explicit "No." otherwise your answer causes a mental page fault.