# Creating annotations within annotations with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, serenity-bdd

Is it possible to nest one annotation inside another with JUnit? For example:

```
@Test
public static void sampleTest() {
    @Test
    public static void innerTest() {
    }
}
```

I'm using Serenity which uses JUnit.

Comment: You can't declare methods inside of methods, so no, this isn't legal.  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... pretty sure that you are going in a very wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to nest one method inside another in Java. If you need one test which will execute another test(or multiple tests) please try:

```
@Test
public static void sampleTest() {
    innerTest1();
    innerTest2();
}
```

If your question is refers to the "can we have annotated members inside method?" Then answer is yes. Since Java 8 you can have even anonymous classes annotated.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3021548/3447032) for more details.